# How to consume binary and String Response using WebClient in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I need to consume a vendor API which returns file(.pdf/.jpg/.png) in binary format when request succeeds while returns a JSON Response when Request fails.
The Request method is of type POST.

I tried using below code:

```
  WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
  ResponseEntity<Object> apiResponse = webClient.post()
                .uri(new URI("https://api.myapp.in/getDocument"))
                .header("mobile", "XXXXXXXXX8")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                //.accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(map))
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(Object.class)
                .block();
```

When i execute the above code it works fine and i am able to get the JSON Response for Error case but when the request is success it gives error as below:

```
 Content type 'application/pdf' not supported for bodyType=java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your get Response, you can `ResponseEntity.getHeaders()`.

From the response headers you can get the content type and consume your response accordingly.
If API does not return valid content-type based on the response, you can raise a defect on the API provider.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it throws exception as soon as the above line is executed. So i dont have  the option to check the headers. i have updated the response for more clarity.

Comment: What is the exception? you can edit your post with more details

Comment: Also, have you tried using curl or postman first, what is the content type you are getting in both the response?

Comment: The exception message is as already mentioned above. I have tried using the postman where in the response section it shows binary format response when the request succeeds and it displays Json response as expected when the request fails.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that is by checking the content type before parsing the response into an object. Check below.

```
    ResponseEntity<Object> apiResponse = webClient.post()
            .uri(new URI("https://api.myapp.in/getDocument"))
            .header("mobile", "XXXXXXXXX8")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(map))
            .exchangeToMono((clientResponse) -> {
                /*Parse binary content*/
                if (clientResponse.headers().contentType().isPresent() && clientResponse.headers().contentType().get().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)) {
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(byte[].class);
                }
                /*Parse text content*/
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(Object.class);
            })
            .block();
```